# Open multiple links in Excel *without* VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have these cells:

- A1: https://www.google.com/
- A2: https://www.facebook.com/
- A3: https://www.bing.com/

Is there some way I can generate a single-click link that opens all of the above links in my default browser (Firefox in my case)?

(I've found some solutions that use VBA. I'm looking for a solution *without* VBA.)

(I use Windows 11 if that matters.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not possible without VBA.

Comment: Yes.  Script your Excel workbook from outside of Excel, using any COM-compatible language (eg, PowerShell, VBScript, JScript, TypeScript, C#.NET, VB.NET, etc.) then manipulate Excel's object model from it.  However, VBA is probably the better option, IMO.